# Symbian panics when deleting dynamic array

Tags: c++, symbian

I am trying to allocate a char array of size 1000. This array
is passed to a function where it should be filled with the data
that has been received from the TCP Socket. The problem occurs
then when I try to delete[] buffer: Here I get as a result a User
Panic 42. Unfortunately, I do not really see what is going wrong
in this simple code fragement...

```
int main
{
    unsigned char *buffer = new unsigned char[1000];
    Recv(&buffer);

    delete[] buffer;        
    return (0);
}

void Recv(unsigned char **buffer)   
{
    TRequestStatus iStatus;
    TSockXfrLength len;

    TBuf8<1000> buff;
    iSocket.RecvOneOrMore( buff, 0, iStatus, len );     
    User::WaitForRequest(iStatus);  

    *buffer = ( unsigned char* )buff.Ptr();  
}
```

Thanks for any useful hints!

Answer (score 5):

What Konrad says is true, but I don't think he knows Symbian. If you do need a function to read bytes into a char buffer, then a better fix would be:

```
void Recv(unsigned char *aBuffer, int aSize)   
{
    TRequestStatus iStatus;
    TSockXfrLength len;

    TPtr8 buff(aBuffer, aSize);
    iSocket.RecvOneOrMore( buff, 0, iStatus, len );         
    User::WaitForRequest(iStatus);  
}
```

TBuf8 is a descriptor which contains an array to hold the data. TPtr8 is a descriptor which refers to an external buffer that you specify. Either can be passed into RecvOneOrMore, since they both inherit from the parameter type, TDes8&. So the socket can be made to write its data directly into your buffer, instead of writing into a buffer on the stack and then copying as Konrad's code does.

You probably also need to check the status to detect errors, and report success/failure and the length written back to the caller.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. So many thanks onebyone and the others with their helpful comments!

Comment: “… but I don't think he knows Symbian” – exactly right. +1 for the improved code.

Answer (score 2):

Your array allocation is without effect because inside the function, you assign a new pointer to the array:

```
*buffer = ( unsigned char* )buff.Ptr();
```

Now the buffer points to another memory location, presumably one that you may not free using `delete` (e.g. one on the stack, or allocated using something other than `new`).

To fix the problem, it's probably best to *copy* the data to your array:

```
void Recv(unsigned char *buffer)   
{
    TRequestStatus iStatus;
    TSockXfrLength len;

    TBuf8<1000> buff;
    iSocket.RecvOneOrMore( buff, 0, iStatus, len );         
    User::WaitForRequest(iStatus);  

    unsigned char* const tmpbuf = static_cast<char*>(buff.Ptr());
    std::copy(tmpbuf, tmpbuf + len, buffer);
}
```

Notice that the `buffer` pointer is now passed directly to the function `Recv`, no further indirection needed since we don't manipulate the pointer directly.

Comment: Your "presumably" is correct, it is on the stack. TBuf8<N> contains an N-byte array.

Comment: And fwiw, the type of buff.Ptr() is TUint8*, and TUint8 is a typedef for unsigned char.

Answer (score 0):

Um, you're trying to delete[] something that's not allocated by you. You're delete[]ing buff.Ptr() while leaking the array allocated in main().